# How do i process Geo Ip Data and put it on Redis

Tags: geolocation, redis, cluster-computing, maxmind

Geo Ip data is very huge so it will take months to expand and put it on redis.How can i use it on cluster so that the file is processed and the data is put on redis server fast.

Comment: Can you expand on your use case? Why do you need this in Redis? If it's very huge, Redis is probably a bad solution since if everything doesn't fit in RAM, Redis starts swapping and you start to experience slow downs. You can always partition, but if your data is, say, 100+ gb, you'll be paying a lot of money to store it all in Redis.

Comment: the expanded file is huge,but i am able to put some 40 lakhs records by using 200 mb ram of one machine.i want to use a cluster to store all ip address against the data from GEO ip ,and if i use it on cluster how will i make sure that all are synchronized at a particular time.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools which will help you to populate the cluster.
one of them is https://github.com/ldodds/redis-load (RUBY GEM)

For partitioning use  range partitioning (based on IP prefixes) read here http://redis.io/topics/partitioning